# Recovering broken drive

Tags: mount, data-recovery

i have a 320 GB external drive which isnt detected automatically when i plug it (neither on Windows7 nor Ubuntu 10.04) Under Windows i can recover the Data with Photorec (but it doesnt preserve names or folder structure, which renders it useless since there are around 200 GB of data) RecoverMyFiles (demo, costs way to much to buy) can also view everything, but the drive makes clicking noises when being accessed  (around 10-20 clicks per minute).

So i switched to Ubuntu and the drive is shown when running fdisk, with no apparent errors, it also stopped clicking. following the steps at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery i used ddrescue to copy whatever i can get to a healthy external drive and it finished without errors but produced only 2 files totaling 3 GB on the healthy drive which i couldnt access. I unmounted the drive and now i cant mount it again with "mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/backup"

I have no idea what to do now. The data is not corrupted but i dont know how to access it. I am afraid to use testdisk because its not very user friendly and i dont want to make irreversible changes that im going to regret later.

Here are the exact commands i used and the fdisk -l output: http://pastebin.com/3XU3hUVK

How do I A) make the healthy drive accessible again and read the data created by ddrescue or B) reformat the healthy drive to be accessible again. and mount the broken drive so i can copypaste everything (or do it with testdisk)